# php56u-mcrypt error: requires libmcrypt.so - vagrant centos 7.0

Tags: php, centos, vagrant

I have a strange issue that I have been running into when trying to download `mcrypt` for `php 5.6 and 7.0.x`.  The error message states:

```
Error: Package: php56u-mcrypt-5.6.30-2.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit)
```

The interesting thing is, I thought this might have been due to maybe a corrupt version of PHP (I was using 7.0.6 before) and received this same message.  So when coming to PHP 5.6, I created a new Vagrant Centos 7.0 machine and I yet again, get this same error message.

Suggestions?